# iPhone - custom UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone

I am showing a UIImagePickerController in an app that just works with videos. So, it is nonsense to show pictures to users.

I have changed all properties I see on the controller but the picker shows like the next picture.

Two questions:

1. How do I get rid of this choice and show just the Photo Library, without having to tap first to get there.
2. As far as I know, all videos shot with iPhone end on camera roll. Suppose the iPad gets a camera in the future. Does this Photo Library option include the camera roll or what?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use this and customize to fit your needs.

http://www.icodeblog.com/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

I found some issues with it, mostly that it takes a while to load on a device when there are 200+ images.  I have not dug into to much, but this might be a start for you.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you can figure out how to speed listing when there are more 200+ images in the library, drop an update here.  I will do the same if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but to access the camera roll directly you just need to set your `UIImagePickerController` source like this:

```
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```